# How to use laravel-vue-pagination in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3.

And want to use the [laravel-vue-pagination](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination).
To do that, I installed the plugin with NPM and I see it in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@meforma/vue-toaster": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
}
```

In `main.js`, I import it like this:

```
import laravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination'
```

and use it like this:

```
const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(laravelVuePagination)
```

and I use it like this in my app:

```
<laravelVuePagination :data="users" @pagination-change-page="getUsers"></laravelVuePagination>
```

It does not work, I have this error in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: laravelVuePagination
```

I am a beginner in Vue, certainly I forgot something somewhere. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the package is compatible with Vue 3. If it is, you're registering it as a plugin, not a component. Try [registering it as a component](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#composing-with-components) to make sure.

Comment: I just tried like you said @Daniel: same problem. I think this component is not for vue.js 3

Answer (score 0):

It might not be compatible but you register the component with

```
.component()
```

not

```
.use()
```